# No C++ jobs link for the wiki C++ wiki tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

If you look up the question lists for [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) or [java](/questions/tagged/java), you'll get a 'c#' or 'java jobs' link below the tag excerpt.

However, not for the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag.

Bug?

Comment: I suspect someone forgot to handle `+` quoting.. http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/c%2b%2b certainly exists.

Comment: Will have this soon, stand by.

Comment: Still not fixed, but can be worked around: If you search for 'C' jobs all jobs tagged with c++ are shown. Would be nice to get fixed though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this fell off the radar. You should see the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).